# WPF MVVM ContentPresenters

Tags: wpf, mvvm, contentpresenter

I am trying to implement a master detail form in WPF. The master shows a list of records (objects) which when one is selected the detail view then just renders that object/shows the fields.

However, how do I put commands in the detail view?

I.E. If user updates a record, how do I save it back?

The view is just bound to the model type, not a view model, and I can't work out how to bind it to a view model and thus access commands.

Comment: You set the view model as the data context and bind to properties on it. What do you have so far? code?